# TibcoRV Daemon rvd or rvdaemon

Tags: java, tibco, tibco-rv

I am new to TibcoRV.

On Windows TibcoRV installation, I can find two executable files in the `bin` folder under the installation directory.

```
rvd.exe
rvdaemon.exe
```

It looks like both of these two are TibcoRV daemon executable. Running either of them launches a TibcoRV process. For TibRV 8.4.2 onward, I can only find `rvd.exe`.

Can some please let me know the difference between these two executables?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked a 7.4.7 installation and there's no `rvdaemon.exe`.  Are the processes byte for byte identical?  I thin it's likely, someone just copied one to the other.